# In SVM, can a support vector not be a training sample?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

For all SVM versions, like c-svm, v-svm, soft margin svm etc., can a support vector not be a training sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't. A support vector is always a sample from the training set.

This is a good thing, because it means SVMs are oblivious to the internal structure of their samples and their support vectors. Only the kernel function, which is separate from the SVM proper, has to know about the structure of samples. While most kernels operate on vectors of numbers, there exist kernels that operate on strings, trees, graphs, you name it.

(Note that *linear* support vector machines can be trained without taking support vectors into account. I.e., when you train a linear model under hinge loss with appropriate regularization using an algorithm such as SGD, you get a model that is equivalent to an SVM with a linear kernel, but where the support vectors are implicit.)

Comment: thanks larsmans, btw, how kernel operate on graphs? could you give an example?

Comment: @jarjar: the idea is that you define a symmetric function K(x,y) that returns larger values as the objects x and y are more similar. I'm not really familiar with graph kernels, but if you take strings as an example, then K could be some function related to the Levenshtein distance D, e.g. 1 / (1 + D(x,y)).